# ReactJS - Passing return Object from State to Prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to follow the ReactJS best practices of using state components when any state changes are possible and props when a component is stateless, but I'm not sure how I am supposed to structure my components to allow for both types. Currently I'm fetching a JSON file and setting the individual objects within a state component and then I would like structure the design and layout of that information with individual prop components for each piece of information, which I believe is the best practice, but the prop components are rendering errors that the property I'm passing is `undefined`. Is this a parent/child component issue?

**Here is my view feed (Top-level, being rendered):**

```
export default class CommentFeed extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="comment-feed">
                <Comments />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Then my fetch and set as a state component:**

```
//Comments List
class Comments extends React.Component{

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = this.context.data || window.__INITIAL_STATE__ || {users: []};
    }

    fetchList() {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/test')
            .then(res => {
                return res.json();
            })  
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                let users = data.map((user, index) => {
                    return(
                        <div key={index}>
                        <UserTitle title={user.title} />
                        <li>{user.discovery}</li>
                        <ul>
                        {
                            user.user_comments.map((comment, i) => {
                                console.log("this is the comment " + JSON.stringify(comment));
                                console.log("this is the i " + i);
                                return (
                                        <div key={comment.userCommentId}>
                                        <h4>{comment.app_user.fullNameSlug}</h4>
                                        <li>{comment.comment}</li>
                                        </div>
                                )
                            })
                        }
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
                this.setState({ users: users });
            })  
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchList();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <h2>Comments List</h2>
            <ul>
            {this.state.users}
            </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
};
```

**And here is the `<UserTitle />` prop component:**

```
class UserTitle extends React.Component{
    render(props){
        return (
            <div className="test">
                <h1>{props.title}</h1>
            </div> 
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I would probably not store the rendered stuff into state? That gives you a pretty bloated state. Set the state as the result of your async, and do the rendering stuff in render. You can put the .map of this.state.users directly in the render-function, or in some sub-render method. 

For components, you can always return null, so if no prop is provided, just return null in the render function?

Comment: it's {this.props.title} not {props.title} also i think render doesn't have any parameters

Comment: i was about to mention the same. Render doesnt have any params, you have to refer to this

Comment: `render` has no parameters, it will receive data as `this.props...`, or `this.state...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on right way of thinking on splitting components to single-purpose ones.

In general in "the community" we have generally 2 types of components:

- container components
- view components (dumb components)

container components should handle the business logic, fetching data, actions etc, and then pass the need data as props to the view components.

view components, dont handle data, not fetching, just displaying the view. mostly they dont even have their own state (not always)

So here is a brief view of what you need to have:
- CommentsContainer
- CommentsFeedView
- CommentView

how it should look basically in the code:

```
class CommentsContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            comments = [],
            loading: false
        }
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        someAjaxCall('get', '/comments')
            .then(data => {
                   this.setState({comments: data, loading: false})
                }).bind(this)
    }

    render() {
        return <CommentsFeedView {...this.state} />
    }
}


const CommentsFeedView = props => {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.comments.map(comment => <CommentView {...comment} />}
        </div>
    )
}

const CommentView = props => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h4>{props.title}</h4>
            <p>{props.content}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

if you would like to create nested maps, you need to change your mindset.
Think of a component as a black box that renders content.
There may be more complex components and less. Components that render other components and one liners.

So this is an example just like the question code you have:

```
class UsersCommentsFeed {
    render() {
        return (
           {this.props.users.map(user => <SingleUserComments {...user} />)}
        )
    }
}

class SingleUserComments {
    render() {
        return (
           {this.props.comments.map(comment => <Comment {...comment} />)}
        )
    }
}

class Comment {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               <h2>{this.props.title}</h2>
               <p>{this.props.content}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

as you can see here, we don't really care about maps, or nested maps. Each component renders itself and doesn't care about the "outside"

Comment: This is a great explanation and thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Is it possible to provide a quick example of what a nested map would look like in the `CommentsFeedView` component? As you may notice in my question, the comments section is a map within the user map

Comment: Sure, so just a list of comments and inside that a list of comments of that comments. Will update later

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `UserTitle` and `<ul>{user.user_comments.map(...)}</ul>` are part of the same `User` component (name as you wish).

Instead of rendering components inside a callback (not recommended because you are saving components into state), my suggestion is creating a single component which takes care of all user details.

It keeps your code and components reusable (`UserTitle` for example) and testable, not to mention you have to update the big `then(data =>...)` business logic every time user has to change somehow.

```
const UserComments = ({ comments }) =>
  <ul>
    {comments.map(comment =>
      <li key={comment.userCommentId}>
        <h4>{comment.app_user.fullNameSlug}</h4>
         <span>{comment.comment}</span>
      </li>
    )}
  </ul>

const User = ({ user }) =>
  <div>
    <UserTitle={user.title} />
    <span>{user.discovery}</span>
    <UserComments comments={user.user_comments} />
  </div>
```

on `fetchList` you can save users array on state:

```
fetchList() {
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/test')
    .then(res => res.json())  
    .then(data => this.setState({ users: data }))
}
```

and on `render`:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Comments List</h2>
      {this.state.users.map((user, index) => <User key={index} user={user} />}
    <div>
  )
}
```